# RIA Services not updating null foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight, code-first, ria

I have a weird issue with RIA Services. I have two entities in my EF CodeFirst (v4.1) context, `Customer` and `Address`, that are in a 1:1 relation to each other.

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // [...]

    [Include, Association("Customer_BillingAddress", "BillingAddressId", "Id")]
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public int? BillingAddressId { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // [...]
}
```

I configured them with the model builder like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.BillingAddress)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.BillingAddressId);
```

as described in [this blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx). It all works like a charm, but when I want to do this on the client:

```
customer.BillingAddress = null;
customer.BillingAddressId = null;
```

RIA Services won't update the ID, leading to a foreign key constraint error on the server. I checked, that the navigation propert yand the foreign key get set to `null` at the time of saving. So it seems like, RIA Services is not tracking the property when I set it to `null`. How can I fix that?

*EDIT:* I completely forgot: It works on my dev machine, but not on the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Ghch... Found the answer [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736825/wcf-ria-services-fails-to-update-a-property-to-the-default-value-of-its-type). Bottom-line: apply the `[RoundtripOriginal]` attribute to the `Customer` class.